# UINavigationBar not updating Color immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the color of the UINavigationBar as the User navigates to a different page. However my App does not change the color of the UINavigationBar until the user backs out of the page and goes back into the page once again. I tried putting the initialization code for changing the color in `-(void)viewDidLoad` and also `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`. Here is how I am currently attempting to change the color:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.32f green:0.14f blue:0.32f alpha:1.00f]];
}
```

Comment: You code changes title bar color for ALL `UINavigationBar` instances. It's application wide proxy. You don't want to use it if you need to change it in just one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like that:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.32f green:0.14f blue:0.32f alpha:1.00f]];
}
```

That code you have changes title bar color for ALL `UINavigationBar` instances. It's application wide proxy. You don't want to use it if you need to change it in just one place.

Comment: the error I am receiving is that UINavigationItem does not have an interface for `setBarTintColor`

Comment: Nevermind, I simply changed `navigationItem` to `navigationBar`

Comment: Right, I was typing from memory. Updated the answer.